# In Java,using Apache POI, how can I pull cell data as is, not the formula?

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv, xls

Some cells have data concatenated from other cells. In trying to write a csv file from the parent file, some cells are written to the csv file by their formula not, the value of said formula.  I need the resulting value, not the formula itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Object getCellValue(HSSFCell cell) {
    if (cell == null) { return null; }
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
        switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: return cell.getNumericCellValue();
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: return cell.getStringCellValue().replaceAll("'", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```